# Get the file from directory

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get all files from a directory and store it inside a variable the process is like When I upload a file,i store it inside a variable ,in this scenario the process will be same but i wont uploading anything , I will be directly sending those files ,
Any help would be much appreciated

This what I tried

```
$dir = public_path('dbf');

      // $new_path = public_path('new_files');

        $files1 = scandir($dir);

        $count=count($files1);
        for($i=1;$i<$count;$i++)
        {
            $file=$files1[$i];
            if($files1[$i]!='.' && $files1[$i]!='..')
            {
                $data=file_get_contents($dir.'/'.$file);
            $name=$data->getClientOriginalName;
            echo $name;

            }
}
```

Its showing me error

> Trying to get property 'getClientOriginalName' of non-object
>   Please solve this for me

inside that folder there is a file named cams_transaction.dbf 
content of that file

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the content of the files inside the `dbf` folder? `file_get_contents` returns the string content of a file not an object.

Comment: inside that folder there is a file named cams_transaction.dbf

Comment: Yes and what is the content of `cams_transaction.dbf` edit your question to show example content.